# Alternative to eval in Python

Tags: python, eval

Python `eval` is quite slow. I need to evaluate simple boolean expression with logical operators (like "True or False"). I am doing this for thousands of line of data and `eval` is a huge bottleneck in terms of performance. It's really slow.. Any alternative approaches?

I tried creating a `dict` of possible expression combinations and their expected output, but this is really ugly!

I have the following code at the moment:

```
eval('%s %s %s' % (True, operator, False))
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing? In 99% of the cases people who use eval really don't need it and will be much better of without it. I'm pretty sure you're in this group.

Comment: well, i just need to evaluate the boolean expression for thousands of lines. as you said, i do fall in the 99% category. the solution below is amazing!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import operator
ops = { 'or': operator.or_, 'and': operator.and_ }
print ops[op](True, False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me how @CatPlusPlus's solution will evaluate any boolean expression.  Here is an example from the pyparsing wiki examples page of a [Boolean expression parser/evaluator](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py).  Here are the test cases for this script:

```
p = True
q = False
r = True
test = ["p and not q",
        "not not p",
        "not(p and q)",
        "q or not p and r",
        "q or not (p and r)",
        "p or q or r",
        "p or q or r and False",
        ]

for t in test:
    res = boolExpr.parseString(t)[0]
    print t,'\n', res, '=', bool(res),'\n'
```

Comment: I have implemented a parser that converts the complex expression into simple boolean expressions (precedence of operators, brackets etc.). At the end of the day I only need to evaluate something like "True or False" etc. so that's why the above solution works for me!