# asking for alternate method apart from eval in python

Tags: python, rules

**Problem i am solving:** i am giving liberty to user to make conditions and actions for making rules while inserting data into a database and evaluate these conditions and action, i could not think anything else from using eval , an example of datastructure i created for such purpose is

```
action_var = ""
a_hash = {"condition":a_condition,
          "action":a_hash}
a_condition ={"param":"abc",
              "operator":">",
              "value":"cde"}
a_action = {"param":action_var,
            "operation":"=",
            "value":"action
```

So my plan is to take condition id from user and action id from user and then use eval to evaluate the expression .

**Help**: Am i going in right direction, is there alternate method to do this ?

**P.S:** I can't use triggers on database, I am kind of using orm wrapper for lmdb. So i use write command at base level.

Edit: i want to have multiple conditions, with and/or mixed, with brackets.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to eval in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882987/alternative-to-eval-in-python)

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer  i want to have multiple conditions, with and/or mixed, with brackets. that alternative you provided only operates on two parameters

Comment: The linked questions doesn't ask about two parameters, neither does the second answer. Feel free to put a bounty on it, if the answers aren't good enough.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `eval`. Map those operators to functions and then apply the functions to the arguments. Consider:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operators = {}
>>> operators['>'] = operator.gt
>>> operators['>'](*[1, 2])
False
>>> 1 > 2
False
```

Comment: thanks, but one problem with it, i want to have multiple conditions, with and/or mixed, with brackets. how will i achieve that ?