# Convert a list of semi-structured text into a formal definition

Tags: python, regex, parsing, automated-tests

I'm trying to implement in Python a script that will automatically convert a list of events defined in a test sequence (ERTMS Subset-076-6-3) into a more formal definition; in order to use this new form to search this events in some log files.

The events are defined in a semi-structured form like this examples:

- "One Balise Group message (NID_BG = BGb) containing packet 255 is received"
- "DMI SYMBOL STATUS (NID_MESSAGE_JRU=21; 
  DMI_SYMB_STATUS=< Bit66=0&Bit68=0&Bit70=0&Bit72=0&Bit74=0&Bit76=0 >) is recorded"
- "The service brake intervention is RECORDED."
- "SA-CONNECT.Confirm is received"
- "SA-DATA.Request with Euroradio Message "Initiation of a communication session" (NID_MESSAGE=155) is transmitted"
- "SA-DATA.Indication with Euroradio Message "RBC/RIU System Version" (NID_MESSAGE=32) is received"
- The driver’s validation action is recorded on the JRU.

My plan for now is to parse every event list and save the values that I can check in logs (i.e. NID_MESSAGE_JRU=21 Bit66=0 Bit68=0 Bit70=0 Bit72=0 Bit74=0 Bit76=0 ) and the name of the function that will correctly evaluate the conditions:

```
def and():
    return(NID_MESSAGE_JRU==21 && Bit66==0 && Bit68==0 && Bit70==0 && Bit72==0 && Bit74==0 && Bit76==0)
```

Then the program will then parse the logs and search for messages that will return True to that function, records the matches a look for other conditions.

Now I'm looking for a way to automate this process as much as I can as there are over 700 test sequence with roughly 80 events each.

After a bit of research I found that using a parser generator would fit my need, but I'm stuck at the sheer amount of them https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/ and I can't choose which one fits my problem better.

The other solution I came up is to evaluate my events with some simple regex and generate the evaluation condition using them and then use eval() to evaluate them after I've loaded the value from the logs:

```
s = "DMI SYMBOL STATUS (NID_MESSAGE_JRU=21; DMI_SYMB_STATUS=<Bit66=0&Bit68=0&Bit70=0&Bit72=0&Bit74=0&Bit76=0>) is recorded"

s1 = s[s.find("(")+1:s.find(" ")]
s2 = s[s.find("<")+1:s.find(">")]
condition = s1 + s2
condition = re.sub('[=]','==',condition)
condition = re.sub('[;&]', '&&',condition)
condition='NID_MESSAGE_JRU==21&&Bit66==0&&Bit68==0
           &&Bit70==0&&Bit72==0&&Bit74==0&&Bit76==0'
```

Do you have any advice about which parse generator will fit my needs? Or should I continue with the regex way? Or am I heading the wrong way completely?

Comment: The baseline 3 tests are available here: http://www.era.europa.eu/Document-Register/Pages/Set-2-Test-Sequences.aspx

Comment: I had trouble downloading the test-sequence files (they kept failing at around 35 MB downloaded); managed to solve this by cross-loading them to my DropBox then downloaded from there.

Comment: So far: the 4 .zip test files contain a total of 733 .zip test cases (slightly over 1 MB each). Each case consists of a .bmp (Windows bitmap) image charting the test scenario (as train speed vs distance), a .doc (Word 97) document laying out the test sequence of events, and an .mdb (Microsoft Access) database containing 29 tables, some of which are empty. I haven't got the database schema figured out yet, but it looks like it basically duplicates the .doc (with a whole bunch of extra stuff shoveled in just because).

Comment: After a deeper research I'll try something along the line of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882987/alternative-to-eval-in-python
As it seems a better and more pythonic way of handing the evaluation of my data instead of using eval().
Also I'll try pyparsing to semi-automatically convert the test sequence, as I don't think I'll be able to define a grammar covering every event.
@HughBothwell Yes sometimes the era website is not very collaborative. Let me know what do you think about my solution, after you've seen the sequences.

Comment: Regarding the test sequences you are right, the database is just a 1 to 1 copy of the doc tables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I should start with a comprehensive list of the strings to be parsed.

I downloaded the test data files (1009 MB) and unpacked them (733 .zip files, 1009 MB). I then wrote

```
from collections import Counter
import glob
import os
import pyodbc
from zipfile import ZipFile

DATA_DIR      = "~/subset076"        # dir containing test-case .zip files
TEMP_DIR      = "~/subset076/temp"
CONN_STR      = r"DRIVER={{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}};DBQ={}"
DATA_TABLE    = "TSW_TCStep"
DATA_FIELD    = "ST_DESCRIPTION"

def get_mdbs():
    for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, "*.zip")):
        zf = ZipFile(fname)
        for member in zf.namelist():
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(member)
            if ext.lower() == ".mdb":
                print("Extracting", member)
                zf.extract(member, path = TEMP_DIR)

def get_test_strings():
    test_strings = Counter()
    sql = "SELECT {} FROM {}".format(DATA_FIELD, DATA_TABLE)
    for fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(TEMP_DIR, "*.mdb")):
        print("Working on", fname)
        with pyodbc.connect(CONN_STR.format(fname)) as conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
            test_strings.update(row[0] for row in cursor)
    return test_strings

get_mdbs()
ts = get_test_strings()
```

which unpacks all the .mdb files (733 files, 718 MB) and grabs all the test sequence event strings. I ended up with 4495 unique strings, 73320 strings in total. Sorted, you get https://pastebin.com/reSGn8JE (about 400 kB).

I'll continue on actually parsing it tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks for your interest! I did the same analysis but came to the conclusion that I can't evaluate some on the events alone as they are linked to each other, for example:

-The driver validates the train data.
-The driver’s validation action is recorded on the JRU.
-The complete set of Train Data is recorded on the JRU.

So at least we need to order that list or a better way seems to analyse each test case alone (a test sequence is formed by a number of test case) as they repeat quite a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do - search through the logs to find test errors? It seems like you'd have to basically implement a tester to see what output you should get, then compare the ideal output to what's actually in the log.

Comment: In any case, the database seems decently organized (although an official schema would be useful and may point out things I missed!). The SC_Interfaces and SC_Internal tables contain the test start conditions; TSW_TCStep has each step of the test, TSW_MessageHeader and TSW_MessageBody contain the messages (commands?) sent at each step, TSW_SpeedProfile has train movements, and EC_Interfaces and EC_Internal give you the expected results.

Comment: Yes I need to generate an ideal output and then compare it to the logs. As you said the EC_interfaces and EC_Internal will cover part of the desired results, but not everything. 
The example I'm referring in my "code" is about the JRU logs that needs to be validated and are not included in that tables, but I could use also the radio simulation (RTM) as an example. 
That's why I need to parse also the events to generate an ideal output.